# show all columns in zend framework

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, fetch

Here is my Zend phtml file :

```
<?php 
foreach ($this ->books as $key =>$value)
{
    echo $value->title.'by'.$value->author.'<br>';
}
```

and result is : 
**first titleby first book

second titleby second book

third titleby third book

fourth titleby fourth book**
"*title*" and "*author*" are two columns of my table,my table has 4 another columns, I just want to iterate over all the columns without knowing their names inside table.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is unclear. Are `title` and `author` the only columns, and you just want to wrap the structure into table? Or they are not, and you want to iterate over all the columns without knowing their names?

Comment: thank you for your comment , I'll change this question, No , they aren't , I wanna iterate over all the columns without knowing their names

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `Refection`.

Try something like this:

```
class A{
    public $prop1 = null;
    public $prop2 = null;
    public $prop3 = null;
    public $prop4 = null;
}

$a1 = new A();
$a1->prop1 = "prop11";
$a1->prop2 = "prop12";
$a1->prop3 = "prop13";
$a1->prop4 = "prop14";


$a2 = new A();
$a2->prop1 = "prop21";
$a2->prop2 = "prop22";
$a2->prop3 = "prop23";
$a2->prop4 = "prop24";

$tab = array($a1,$a2);

foreach($tab as $key => $value){
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_class($value));

    $properties = $reflector->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
    $var_out = "";
    foreach($properties as $property){
        $var_out .= ", " . $property->getName() . " = ". $value->{$property->getName()};
    }
    echo trim($var_out, ", ") . "<br>";
}
```